# Video Recording on iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, recording

I have this iPhone app, which plays streaming video from a source(Just video, no audio).
Is there any mechanism by which i can capture this streaming video or record them, for later playback?

Answer (score 0):

There are two APIs for downloading a file and saving to the photos and videos album.

```
* NSURLConnection for file downloads
* UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum to save a video to the photo album
```